# Store Get Method Results Into Variable And Display It

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function:

```
<div class="tempatbaca"></div>
<script>
    function bacaData() {
          $.get("a.php", {}, function (data, status) {
              $(".tempatbaca").html(data);
          });
      }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    bacaData();
  });
</script>
```

a.php file just contain an echo "Hi".
That code is work fine. But how to store the get method result to variable?
I try this:

```
<script>
    var data2;
    function bacaData() {
          var a;
          $.get("a.php", {}, function (data, status) {
              a = data; 
          });
          return a;
      }

    data2 = bacaData();

    $(document).ready(function(){
    //initialize the javascript
    document.getElementById("tempatbaca").innerHTML = data2; 
  });
</script>
```

And result's didn't appear. Did I wrong?

Comment: What have you done to try to diagnose the problem?  Have you used a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous. So, your code returns `a` before it gets assigned a value. Whereas, in your upper version of code you are assigning inside the callback and hence it works fine. Have a look at JavaScript's [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 0):

Because `$.get` take a time to get data from the server, your function `bacaData` return `a` before `$.get` done.

You can use the code below to do the same.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("a.php", {}, function (data, status) {
          document.getElementById("tempatbaca").innerHTML  = data; 
    });
});
```